# COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder073318368/Pipfile: no such file or directory

Tags: django, docker, django-views, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile. also you can see the image of Dockerfile

```
   #Dockerfile
   # Pull base image
   FROM python:3.6
   # Set environment variables
   ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
   ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
   # Set work directory
   WORKDIR /code

   # Install dependencies
   COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
   RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

   # Copy project
   COPY . /code/
```

#Dcokerfile image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvcAD.png

When i run this file it gives me error. I run this file using command (>docker build .) on ubuntu 18.04 for the testing simple django project.

Comment: That error message essentially says the `Pipfile` isn't in the same directory as the `Dockerfile` (more specifically the `.` directory at the end of the `docker build .` command).  Is it in the right place on the host system?

Answer (score 0):

Change the following lines:

```
FROM python:3.6
# set work directory
WORKDIR /code

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install project dependencies
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY ./Pipfile /code/Pipfile
COPY ./Pipfile.lock /code/Pipfile.lock
RUN pipenv lock --requirements > /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

COPY . /code/
```

Comment: Why oh why would you do that? His problem is with the COPY - the rest isn't relevant and assumes you don't want it to run in a virtual env.

Comment: Installation using pipenv is slower, don't need a virtualenv inside the docker container.

Comment: Yes, I missed the --system flag. However, it works slightly different: `pipenv lock -r` will create the virtualenv whereas `pipenv install --system` will not. It's also less steps and easier to switch to a virtualenv if you want to do so.

Comment: It uses the lockfile to generate a requirements.txt file, without creating a virtual environment. Could you cite your source/docs?

Comment: I just did it locally. `pipenv --rm ; pipenv lock -r`. [here](https://pastebin.com/XUxZUTVY)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue but i solved by use
RUN pip install pipenv before copy as below

```
# Install dependecies
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pipenv install --system
```